# DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 48: The MAC is invalid. in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I am getting this error when i sent a post request to my resource controller. My controller code is

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //return $request->all(); (here i am checking values sometimes showing values and sometimes showing the mac error.)
    $tags = $request->input('tags');
        if(!empty($tags)){
            $tags = implode(",", $tags);
        }
    //return $request->from;
    $status = FamousPost::create([

        'name' => $request->input('from'),
        'to_name' => $request->input('to'),
        'title' => $request->input('title'),
        'content' => $request->input('content'),
        'avatar' => $request->input('from_avatar'),
        'to_avatar' => $request->input('to_avatar'),
        'tags' => $tags

    ]);

    if($status)
        return json_encode(true);
    else
        return json_encode(false);
}
```

Sometimes values are coming from request and sometimes(mostly) i am getting the  MAC error. My frontend is angularjs i am submitting the form using `$http service` of angularjs.

Comment: may i know the reasons for down vote this question?

Comment: Kindly visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49788839/decryptexception-in-baseencrypter-php-line-48-the-mac-is-invalid-laravel-5-2?noredirect=1#comment86592678_49788839) for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your .env file. There should be space between APP_KEY and APP_DEBUG

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. my .env file is fine. The problem is some other.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }} "/>
```

add this field in your form