# DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 48: The MAC is invalid. laravel 5.2

Tags: php, encryption, laravel-5

I know this question has already been asked. But none of them solve my issue.

I am facing the issue : DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 48:
The MAC is invalid.

I checked my .env file there is no space in **APP_DEBUG** and **APP_KEY**

Tried to generate new key but nothing worked out.

**Laravel Framework version 5.2.45**

Comment: Post the code...

Comment: Why down vote. What is the issue.

Comment: Read my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

After surfing for around two hours , tried so many solution form different sources but none of them solved my problem.

1. There may be reason then .env file have space in APP_DEBUG and APP_KEY key.

   By removing the space if exists can solve the problem.
2. By clearing cache, composer dump-autoload can also be used in some cases.
3. But in my case the issue was either

   **DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 48: The MAC is invalid**

   or

   **DecryptException in BaseEncrypter.php line 45: The payload is invalid**

   The issue was because of database column issue.

   The column type was `varchar` and length was `256` that was creating whole issues. As field `mwsAuthToken` has lenght more then filed `256` and was truncating the `mwsAuthToken` key value.

   Thus by changing the field type to **text** solved my problem.